# Agario in JavaScript - Player not Moving

Tags: javascript

I am having problem with my code,

```
// JavaScript Document
var canvas = document.getElementById("PlayingArea");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
var foodArray = [];
var size = 10;
var food;


var player1 = {x:150, y:150};

//create Player1
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fill();

function update() {
    "use strict";

    //BG Refresh
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);


    document.addEventListener("keydown", Player1Control);
    function Player1Control(){ 
        if(event.keyCode === 38) {
            player1.y--;
        }
        if(event.keyCode === 40) {
            player1.y++;
        }
        if(event.keyCode === 39) {
            player1.x++;
        }
        if(event.keyCode === 37) {
            player1.x--;
        }
    }

    if (player1.x >= canvasWidth) {
        player1.x = canvasWidth;
    } else if (player1.x <= 5) {
        player1.x = 5;
    }

    if (player1.y > canvasHeight) {
        player1.y = canvasHeight;
    } else if (player1.y <= 5) {
        player1.y = 5;
    }

    //Player Show
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(player1.x, player1.y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();

    //Food Show
    for(var i=foodArray.length; i>0; i--){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc({x:foodArray[i].x},{y:foodArray[i].y} , size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
    }


    setTimeout(update, 10);
}

function foodGen(){
    "use strict";
    food = {x:Math.round(Math.random()*(canvasWidth)), 
    y:Math.round(Math.random()*(canvasHeight))};
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(food.x, food.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();
    foodArray.push({x:1,y:1});
    setTimeout(foodGen, 1000);
}


update();
foodGen(0,750);
```

The player is not show in my code and I do not know why my player isn't Moving.
I am pretty new at JavaScript and HTML/CSS. This is my first time Stack overflow so I am sorry for any derps.

-lt1489

edit: My player now appears on the screen, can't be moved.
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/5os0qrhp/2/

Comment: Since you don't change `fillStyle` between clearing the canvas and drawing the player, you are drawing the player white. Since it is white on white, you cannot see the player.

Comment: @keizom Thanks so much for that but I have just encountered another problem. The Player isn't moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question was answered with the following comment:

> Since you don't change fillStyle between clearing the canvas and drawing the player, you are drawing the player white. Since it is white on white, you cannot see the player.

Regarding the second issue, move `document.addEventListener` and `Player1Control` to outside `update`. Additionally, `Player1Control` needs `event` as an argument, resulting in:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", Player1Control);
function Player1Control(event) { ... }
function update() { ... }
```

---

A few syntax changes fixes the code. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5os0qrhp/3/) to see those changes outlined.